# How to pass string value from javascript to controller?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am using javaScript in Visualforce page to set the value of String variable. How can I pass this updated value to the controler?

```
  function saveFunctionality()
        { document.getElementById('VWValveSearch:VWSiteTemplate:frm1:pressureClass').value = 'Please have this value';
                   validateSaveInputFields();     
            }           

 <apex:actionFunction id="validateSaveInputFields" name="validateSaveInputFields" action="{!btnAddToProject}"  reRender="dummy" > </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction id="validateSaveInputFields" name="validateSaveInputFields" action="{!btnAddToProject}"  reRender="dummy" > 
</apex:actionFunction>
```

The reason why I am using javascript is because the strPressureClass is a string variable and when I click on save button. Sometimes it has value or sometime it has Null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a variable to a formfield you can add the variablename to the value using the following syntax: `{!variableName}`.

**This would be an example:**

*Visualforce Page:*

```
<apex:inputHidden id="returnString" value="{!returnString}" />
<apex:commandButton onclick="return functionToSetReturnString();" value="Submit" action="{!actionInController}"></apex:commandButton>
```

*Apex Controller:*

```
public String returnString { get; set; }
public void actionInController () {
    // Read your returnString here using this.returnString
}
```

*JavaScript code in Visualforce Page for example in `functionToSetReturnString` (replace  with the id of your apex-form):*

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.idOfYourForm.returnString}').value = "Your String to pass to the controller";
```

Comment: Can you tell me Why I am having null values in String Variable or not having the updated value while I am seeing the value in a VF page and When I save the record it's Gone.

Comment: Maybe the value is overwritten in a function that is called on save? I suggest checking every assignment of the variable in the controller and the visualforce page.

Comment: I double checked. I am not even using it anywhere. The problem I am facing is that there are too many javascript functions calls on single onchange of picklist and When I try to save it, it shows uncertain behavior.

Comment: I am showing and hiding the picklists values based on javascript function then pass it to the controller, based on query results it shows price. When I try to save the record it saves picklists values mostly and misses the text values that came from the database.

Comment: Then I guess something is wrong with your code, but not with passing the string to the controller. I use the proposed solution myself and this works fine. Maybe your javascript-code in the visualforce page is somehow erroneous. The multiple triggered events could be solved by using the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/blur). I suggest accept this answer for passing values to the controller and open a new question for the followup-problem that includes the complete code and a further description of the problem.

Comment: OK can you tell me the hierarchy if I call 4 javascript function at a time on on-change function and function 4 is using value of function 3 and so on.  Is it Possible to do that?

Comment: No this isn't possible if the functions are all called at the same time by the same event. I suggest calling one function from another or using a framework/utility that takes care of this to make sure the functions are called in the desired order.

Comment: How can I use framework/utility inside Visualforce page with javascript?

Comment: [apex:includeScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_includeScript.htm) should help.

Comment: One last thing can you tell me how can I pass value to the controller using javascript? When I try above code it only shows on front side (using alert) but not getting it in the controller. +10

Comment: I thought this was obvious, but I updated the answer to be more complete. you can access this via this.returnString and in the action of your form this should be available.